# XAML - user re-ordering of child windows (basically jquery UI sortable for XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a Grid in a WPF application, which contains of 3 groupboxes and has grid-splitters between them.
I want to allow the user reordering of those 3 groupboxes as he wishes, so any mapping of the groupboxes to {left,center,right} positions is allowed.

In web-development world, I would use jQuery UI sortable to solve this.

Is there anything to solve this task for a Grid in WPF? Or any other container, that would provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make 3 columns in your grid, and reorder the items by changing `Grid.Column` attached property. Your initial XAML will look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0"> <!-- contains 1st groupbox --> </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1"> <!-- contains 2nd groupbox --> </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="2"> <!-- contains 3rd groupbox --> </Border>
</Grid>
```

If you need to move the parts by drag-and-drop, you'll need to implement it manually, at least I am not aware of any framework which allows this out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. The task wont be performed often, so implementing the dragging manually wouldnt pay off. If no one comes up with anything for that, I will look for other UI solution for that, maybe just "move left" and "move right" arrows for the groupboxes.

Comment: I didnt find a way of drag and drop without ugly code. Acceptable solution are small arrows "move left", "move right" in case of a few boxes.